# Result of one query into another query

Tags: sql, oracle, nested

I have two tables
TABLE_A with columnname
**COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3 COLUMN4 COLUMN5** and which has data

abc     def     ghi     jkl     mno

123     456     789     001     121

TABLE_B with columnname
**COLUMN6 COLUMN7** which has data as

COLUMN5 124

COLUMN4 bca

COLUMN3 aaa

COLUMN5 bbb

So I have the columnname of Table_A as a data in the table_B

so I want to do something like this in a single query

$query1= select COLUMN6 from TABLE_B where COLUMN7='aaa';

$query2= select $query1 from TABLE_A where COLUMN1='123';

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What if the first query comes back blank? ..it will break the second query.

Comment: Could you explain more extensively what you are trying to do? Could you post the desired output?

Comment: Query1 will give me column name for TABLE_A so it wont come blank

Comment: Query1 will give output as COLUMN3 and Query2 will do select COLUMN3 from TABLE_A where COLUMN1='123' and give me result 789

Comment: Sounds like you need to wrap these two SQL statements around a programming language and have it dynamically generate the second SQL statement.  It's generally inadvisable to generate dynamic SQL, but that sounds like what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a value to match from table a -> to table B
If it looks like this:

TableA -> id, name
TableB -> id, table_a_id, name

This query will work:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM tableA as a
JOIN tableB as b ON a.id=b.table_a_id AND b.name='123'
WHERE a.name='aaaa'
```

To get the names of table A and B. I am using an alias for the table names here to make it easier to read. I hope, with this example, this will answer your question.

If you don't have any matching values, but you want to have all columns crossed, you can do this:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM tableA a, tableB b
WHERE a.name='aaa' AND b.name='123'
```

Comment: I cannot use what you have given since I dont know which column to go to. As I have given in the example Data, query1 will give me one of the three column as a result COLUMN3 or COLUMN4 or COLUMN5 and then only I can go to table_A and query that table

Comment: I don't think it's possible what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You may use CASE or DECODE to do that:

```
select a.* from tableA a, tableB b
WHERE
b.column7 = 'aaa'
and case
when b.column6 = 'COLUMN1' then a.column1
when b.column6 = 'COLUMN2' then a.column2
when b.column6 = 'COLUMN3' then a.column3
when b.column6 = 'COLUMN4' then a.column4
when b.column6 = 'COLUMN5' then a.column5
else null end = '123' -- condition for tableA
```

You can make this statement up to 1000 columns (ORACLE hard limit) :)